# What's wrong with my django URL?

Tags: python, html, django, django-admin, django-views

line from urls.py:

```
url(r'^(?P<customer_profile_id>\d+)/case/(?P<account_type>\w+)/$', view='case', name='case'),
```

line from html:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'case/cash/' %}" id="create_collection_case" target="_blank">
```

error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /admin/customers/1/
Reverse for 'case/cash/' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

I just have an html form -> posting to a django url -> loading a django view. I get the above error when loading the page. Let me know if you need anything else to troubleshoot!

Answer (score 1):

Specify the name of the url (`case`), not the part of the url:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'case' %}" id="create_collection_case" target="_blank">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression needs to match perfectly with the form action if you want django to determine the route. Please note that `\d+` represents integers and I prefer to match texts/strings with `([-\w+]+)`.

For best practises I will advice you change your URL re to (always best to have your integer query value at the end)

```
url(r'^case/(?P<account_type>[-\w+]+)/(?P<customer_profile_id>\d+)/$', view='case', name='case'),
```

and your form action should take this, where profile_id is an integer

```
{% url 'case/cash/profile_id/' %}
#e.g. http://127.0.0.1:8000/case/cash/1/
```